Redis cache implementation using express js and mongoose
I am beginner in redis cache. I have an application in express js , uses mongoose for mongo db. There are two collections named users and payments.
Here I used join of both collection while I fetch data from mongo db . Here I used mongoose.
Now I want to implement redis caching. As I know redis works based on key value pair. I need guideline.

How can I make join query to get both collection data ?
Besides If I make any update on collection data then how it will reflect?
May I use mongoose as well on redis ?
Where may I get details / learn of that ?

Please suggest me best practices.

You want to know How can you use redis in Node,Express.js application? right? It would be descriptive answer. And yes You can use both MongoDB & redis in your application. Upon your detailed response I can provide a general idea about how can you use redis in node,express.js application.
